# comma (,) in C Macro Definition

Tags: c, syntax, macros, c-preprocessor

I've never seen this syntax before.

```
#define SNS(s) (s),(sizeof(s)-1)
```

The way i'm reading this is that `SNS(s) = sizeof(s)-1`.  What is the comma doing?  Is it necessary?

```
int     ft_display_fatal(const char *err, unsigned len, int fd, int rcode)
{ 
    UNUSED(write(fd, err, len));
    return (rcode);
}
```

Main

```
return (ft_display_fatal(SNS("File name missing.\n"), 2, 1));
```

Comment: @chux check edit

Comment: Sounds like it may be intended as "string 'n' size".

Comment: `#define SNS(s) (s),(sizeof(s)-1)` appears to be a way to pass a _string literal_ and its string _length_ in one combined code.  IMO, not a worthy short-cut.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Macros are just text replacement, so they can expand to just about anything you want. In this case, the macro is being used to expand into two arguments to a function. The function expects a string and the number of characters in the string as arguments, and the `SNS()` macro generates them. So

```
ft_display_fatal(SNS("File name missing.\n"), 2, 1)
```

expands into

```
ft_display_fatal(("File name missing.\n"),(sizeof("File name missing.\n")-1), 2, 1)
```

This is basically only useful when the parameter is a string literal: `sizeof("string")` is the size of the `char` array including the trailing null byte, and `-1` subtracts that byte to get the number of significant characters in the string. This is the `len` argument to the `ft_display_fatal` function (I'm not sure why it can't just use `strlen()` to get this by itself -- I guess it's a performance optimization).

Comment: 1) Oops. sorry for that, that is why I rolled back.  2) An uncommon reason for `sizeof(s)-1` vs. `strlen()` is to determine the the "length" of the _string literal_ even if it contained embedded _null character_ - a rare situation.

Comment: I thought **I** rolled it back. Anyway, while that's a possible use, it's very clearly not the intent in this case. The macro is designed specifically to work with that function, which is used to write text.

Comment: Yes the "performance optimization" is a more likely scenario.  Given that it is a  _fatal message_, minimal processing is a wise choice.

Answer (score 4):

> The way i'm reading this is that SNS(s) = sizeof(s)-1.

You are reading it wrong.

> What is the comma doing?

Macro expansion results in *textual* substitution. You can use `SNS(a)` to pass *two* arguments to a function.

> `ft_display_fatal(SNS("File name missing.\n"), 2, 1)`

You can see that `ft_display_fatal` takes 4 arguments, but only 3 are provided. This works *because* `SNS` expands to 2 arguments. If it didn't, you'd get a compiler error.